# What does the phrase "would have it" mean in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What does have mean in this sentence?

> It does not, as a popular myth **would have it**, convey 50% of the actual message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply a variation on the expression [**rumour/word/legend has it that**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/rumour-word-legend-has-it-that). Here's how the Macmillan Dictionary defines it:

> used for showing that you are reporting something that you have heard when you are not sure whether it is really true
>
> *Rumour has it that her husband is not the father of the child.*

To make it easier to understand, the sentence can be paraphrased as follows:

> [**Contrary to popular (mistaken) belief**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/contrary-to-popular-belief), it does not convey 50% of the actual message.

What that popular myth is and what exactly does not convey 50% of the actual message are hard to tell without more context, but the idea here is that there is supposedly a popular myth according to which something does not convey 50% of the actual message.

Comment: Can you please convert this sentence to a more simpler english?